# response.xpath or response.css is not returning any result though correct path value is passed in scrapy framework

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm trying to scrape some data from https://www.moneycontrol.com/markets/indian-indices/. However, I am stuck with below step that it doesn't return any result though i have provided correct xpath values. Any help is appreciated.

```
countries = response.xpath('//*[@id="indices_stocks"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody[2]/tr/td[1]/p/a/text()').getall()

countries = response.css('#indices_stocks > div.indices > div > div > div > div.pinned > table > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr > td:nth-child(1) > p > a::text').getall()
```

result:

[scraping_result_using_xpath_and_css selectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FZI6.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your locators are wrong.
Try this:

```
countries = response.xpath('//table/tbody[2]/tr/td[1]/p/a')
```

Answer (score -1):

Browsers add tbody tag to tables while scrapy doesn't. So usually it's best not to add it to your xpath.

The xpath path is wrong and can be written much shorter:

```
In [4]: response.xpath('//table[@class="responsive"]//a/text()').getall()
Out[4]: 
['Asian Paints',
 'Axis Bank',
 'Bajaj Auto',
 'Bajaj Finance',
 'Bajaj Finserv',
 'Bharti Airtel',
 'Dr Reddys Labs',
 'HCL Tech',
 'HDFC',
 'HDFC Bank',
 'HUL',
 'ICICI Bank',
 'IndusInd Bank',
 'Infosys',
 'ITC',
 'Kotak Mahindra',
 'Larsen',
 'M&M',
 'Maruti Suzuki',
 'Nestle',
 'NTPC',
 'Power Grid Corp',
 'Reliance',
 'SBI',
 'Sun Pharma',
 'Tata Steel',
 'TCS',
 'Tech Mahindra',
 'Titan Company',
 'UltraTechCement',
 'SENSEX',
 'S&P BSE Smallcap',
 'S&P BSE Midcap',
 'S&P BSE SmallCap Select Index',
 'S&P BSE MidCap Select Index',
 'S&P BSE LargeCap',
 'S&P BSE AllCap',
 'S&P BSE 100',
 'S&P BSE 200',
 'S&P BSE 500',
 'S&P BSE BANKEX',
 'S&P BSE Auto',
 'S&P BSE Basic Materials',
 'S&P BSE Capital Goods',
 'S&P BSE Consumer Discretionary Goods & Services',
 'S&P BSE Consumer Durables',
 'S&P BSE Energy',
 'S&P BSE Finance',
 'S&P BSE FMCG',
 'S&P BSE Healthcare',
 'S&P BSE India Mfg',
 'S&P BSE Industrials',
 'S&P BSE IPO',
 'S&P BSE IT',
 'S&P BSE Metals',
 'S&P BSE Oil and Gas',
 'S&P BSE Power',
 'S&P BSE PSU',
 'S&P BSE Realty',
 'S&P BSE TECk',
 'S&P BSE Telecom',
 'S&P BSE Utilities',
 'S&P BSE Dividend Stability Index',
 'S&P BSE Enhanced Value Index',
 'S&P BSE Low Volatility Index',
 'S&P BSE Momentum Index',
 'S&P BSE Quality Index',
 'S&P BSE SENSEX 50 Index',
 'S&P BSE 150 MidCap',
 'S&P BSE 250 SmallCap',
 'S&P BSE 250 LargeMid',
 'S&P BSE 400 MidSmall',
 'NIFTY 50',
 'NIFTY NEXT 50',
 'NIFTY Midcap 100',
 'NIFTY MIDCAP 50',
 'NIFTY 100',
 'NIFTY 500',
 'NIFTY AUTO',
 'NIFTY BANK',
 'NIFTY ENERGY',
 'NIFTY FMCG',
 'NIFTY INFRA',
 'NIFTY IT',
 'NIFTY MEDIA',
 'NIFTY METAL',
 'NIFTY MNC',
 'NIFTY PHARMA',
 'NIFTY PSE',
 'NIFTY PSU BANK',
 'NIFTY REALTY',
 'NIFTY SERV SECTOR',
 'INDIA VIX',
 'SX40',
 'NIFTY GROWSECT 15',
 'NIFTY50 VALUE 20',
 'NIFTY DIV OPPS 50',
 'NIFTY MID LIQ 15',
 'NIFTY100 QUALITY 30',
 'NIFTY Smallcap 100',
 'NIFTY COMMODITIES',
 'NIFTY CONSUMPTION',
 'NIFTY FIN SERVICE',
 'NIFTY PVT BANK',
 'NIFTY MIDCAP 150',
 'NIFTY MIDSML 400',
 'NIFTY Smallcap 250',
 'NIFTY Smallcap 50',
 'SENSEX',
 'S&P BSE Auto',
 'S&P BSE Metals',
 'S&P BSE Oil and Gas',
 'NIFTY 50',
 'NIFTY NEXT 50',
 'NIFTY Midcap 100',
 'NIFTY 100',
 'NIFTY BANK',
 'NIFTY FMCG',
 'NIFTY INFRA',
 'NIFTY IT',
 'NIFTY PHARMA']
```

Comment: If you have a problem with my answer (that works by the way) then dow vote without telling me what's wrong with it?